# Django CSRF validation, when it's not turned on?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.3

I'm trying to post some data from one python application to a django site using urllib, as they are separate programs.

Now i don't have CSRF middleware enabled and I've specifically got @csrf_exampt on the view. It's still failing with a CSRF validation failure.

Is there any way to completely remove csrf? (the django app will be offline so it's not needed)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django CSRF framework cannot be disabled and is breaking my site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650941/django-csrf-framework-cannot-be-disabled-and-is-breaking-my-site)

Comment: I already have the @csrf_exempt decorator and so the posted duplicate does not help.

Comment: Is your django site running in debug mode or on Apache? If it's running in Apache, see if this helps: http://harthur.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/configure-apache-to-accept-cross-site-xmlhttprequests-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I'm using the development server and not apache (will eventually deploy to gunicorn + nginx)