# How to disable Django's CSRF validation?

Tags: python, django

I have commented out csrf processor and middleware lines in `settings.py`:

```
122 
123 TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
124     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
125 #    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
126     'django.core.context_processors.request',
127     'django.core.context_processors.static',
128     'cyathea.processors.static',
129 )
130 
131 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
132     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
133     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
134 #    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
135     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
136     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
137     'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
138     # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
139     # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
140 )
```

But when I use Ajax to send a request, Django still respond 'csrf token is incorrect or missing', and after adding X-CSRFToken to headers, the request would succeed.

What is going on here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650941/django-csrf-framework-cannot-be-disabled-and-is-breaking-my-site

Answer (score 314):

If you just need some views not to use CSRF, you can use `@csrf_exempt`:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

You can find more examples and other scenarios in the Django documentation:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#edge-cases

Comment: Hi, @TheBronx, I really want to know why my solution doesn't work.

Comment: sorry @MrROY I don't know why your solution is not working. I just know that `@csrf_exemp` works as I've used it recently without problems. Hope you find the answer.

Comment: @MrROY, It is a Django thing. Most things do work/doesn't work just because there is a magic setting buried deep down the code base.

Comment: A reminder: if you have other decorators in the same view the order is relevant: so place @csrf_exempt first.

Comment: Hmm-  maybe a technically correct answer, but most certainly not what the OP wanted or what I was looking for.

Comment: And what do I do if I need *all* views not to use CSRF?

Answer (score 64):

In `setting.py` in MIDDLEWARE you can simply remove/comment this line:

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

Comment: this works for me on Django 2.1 using curl as an http client.

Comment: @xtrinch Make sure you fully quit/re-launch the server process. I don't think the auto-relaod picks up the change

Comment: Django `3.2.9` does not require me to restart the server (`python manage.py runserver` command)

Answer (score 60):

To disable CSRF for class-based views, the following worked for me.

I'm using Django 1.10 and Python 3.5.2

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class TestView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

Answer (score 47):

The problem here is that SessionAuthentication performs its own CSRF validation. That is why you get the CSRF missing error even when the CSRF Middleware is commented.
You could add @csrf_exempt to every view, but if you want to disable CSRF and have session authentication for the whole app, you can add an extra middleware like this -

```
class DisableCSRFMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

I created this class in myapp/middle.py
Then import this middleware in Middleware in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'myapp.middle.DisableCSRFMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]
```

That works with DRF on django 1.11

Comment: Thank you for actually giving an answer to the question instead of just posting a solution.

Comment: I followed your solution but I get this error: ```'str' object has no attribute 'get'```. My django version is 3.2.6 though. @Madhuri

Comment: You bloody legend!

Answer (score 18):

For **Django 2**:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class DisableCSRF(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
```

That middleware must be added to `settings.MIDDLEWARE` when appropriate (in your test settings for example).

*Note: the setting isn't not called `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` anymore.*

Answer (score 13):

The answer might be inappropriate, but I hope it helps you

```
class DisableCSRFOnDebug(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if settings.DEBUG:
            setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
```

Having middleware like this helps to debug requests and to check csrf in production servers.

Comment: Hmm.  Tried this in Django 1.9.1.   Removed the @csrf_exempt decorator from the method and added the code above.  Got a 403 because the cookie was not set.

Answer (score 9):

If you want disable it in Global, you can write a custom middleware, like this

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class DisableCsrfCheck(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, req):
        attr = '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks'
        if not getattr(req, attr, False):
            setattr(req, attr, True)
```

then add this class `youappname.middlewarefilename.DisableCsrfCheck` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` lists, before `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`

Answer (score 5):

### Before using this solution, please read [this link from documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#contrib-and-reusable-apps)

---

I solved this problem with the following two steps:

1. Add this class to an `utils.py` file:

   ```py
   from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

   from <your-project-name> import settings
   class DisableCSRF(MiddlewareMixin):
      def process_request(self, request):
         if settings.DEBUG:
            setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
   ```
2. And in the `settings.py` file, add above middleware to the `MIDDLEWARE` list:

   ```py
   ...
   MIDDLEWARE = [
       ...
       'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
       ...
       '<path-of-utils.py>.utils.DisableCSRF',
   ]
   ...
   ```

Comment: where d you import `MiddlewareMixin` from?

Comment: @Nikko `from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin`

Answer (score 1):

CSRF can be enforced at the view level, which **can't be disabled globally**.

In some cases this is a pain, but um, "it's for security". Gotta retain those AAA ratings.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#contrib-and-reusable-apps