# get forbidden response when using phonegap upload filetransfer and django

Tags: django, cordova, upload, django-csrf

i want to upload image using upload method of filetransfer of phonegap this is my html client code : 
    
    
    
     File Transfer Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {

        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
                                    function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                                    { quality: 50, 
                                    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY }
                                    );

    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://myserverUrl/uploadview", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<p>Upload File</p>
</body>
</html>
```

in the server side i have a forbiddenhttpresponse , i know that is due to csrf property but i don't konw how to solve it because my client doesn't in django template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to disable CSRF check for that view.
Check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458216/273119