# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. When I send POST request

Tags: django

I am sending a POST request to my server from an android application, but I am getting this error:

[image]

The POST looks like:
http://example/my_page_url/1000
Where the 1000 is an ID.

This is my views method:

```
def inventory(request, cross_id):

    text_file = open("test.txt", "w")
    text_file.write('POST Received')

    text_file.write(cross_id.__str__())
    text_file.close()

    return render(request, 'Inventory.html', {})
```

my template code:

```
<form action='' method="POST">

     <button type="submit" id="btn_save" name="btn_save">Save</button>

    {% csrf_token %}

</form>
```

Actually, I don't really need to call a template, because I want to perform something on the server only. But I am calling the template just to prevent any errors for now.

I have read the other answers for the same problem but all of them have missed the CSRF token in the template or something else in the views method, but I believe the case is different here.

Comment: Are you actually posting that form or something else?

Comment: No,
The POST is comming from an android APP.
And for testing I am now posting from Postman app to get the error message.

Comment: Well then yes you would, you need to include a valid csrf token in your post request

Comment: @NawwarMokayes also take care of CORS.

Comment: Yea thank you
I have to search how to do this.
I've never tried to include the token from an outer request.
Thanks

Comment: Is ```django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware``` in your middleware settings?

Comment: yea sure, it does exist :D

Answer (score 14):

You need to add the `X-CSRFToken` header to all your POST requests.

You can get the appropriate value for this header from the cookie named `csrftoken`.

To test this in Postman, you need to enable the Interceptor plugin (top right corner).

Once you have it installed, make a `GET` request to `/admin/login/` (make sure you are logged out from the site in the browser). In the cookies section you should see a cookie named `csrftoken`, copy its value.

Now, set the request type to `POST` for the same URL (`/admin/login`), add a header named `X-CSRFToken` with the value you copied earlier. Set the `username` and `password` fields in the `Body` section and hit send.

[image: X-CSRFToken]

If your POST do not require authentication, you can use the `csrftoken` from an earlier GET request.

Comment: Hi @Kedar do I need to provide `username` and `password` and **login** to the page while making a `GET` request to `/admin/login` or just visit the page without logging in to get the **csrftoken** value?

Comment: @aspiring1 Just visiting the page (GET request without login details) is sufficient

Comment: What if I have only `POST ` request enabled for my application? How can I get the csrf token in this scenario

Comment: You can remove CSRF checks in that case https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458216/1268926