# How to send data from external python script to django view

Tags: python, django

I've written a python script on my raspberry pi. I want to send it to my django view function, but I keep running into csrf token issues. I've read about the work around using the decorator, but I want to know if there is a more clean way in sending data to a django view.

Comment: You can use APIView, the csrf issue will be resolved

Comment: So by making my backend a django rest framework would help resolve this issus ?

Comment: I mean Yes. alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458166/how-to-disable-djangos-csrf-validation

Comment: I have tried what you suggest, I was looking for something with more security and not working around the csrf token.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115766/is-a-jwt-usable-as-a-csrf-token