# CSRF cookie error after Django 3.2 update (DRF with token authentication)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I was looking to update my app backend from Django 3.1.14 (working fine but no longer supported) to a newer version (I tried both 3.2 and 4.0), but after updating I started getting a CSRF cookie error.

> Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api-token-auth/

Does anybody by any chance know what's changed in Django in regard to CSRF, and how to avoid the errors?

I was under the impression that CSRF is not enforced when using Django Rest Framework with token authentication. I tried anyway to remove the `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` middleware, to add `@csrf_exempt` to all the views, deleted all existing tokens and logged out of Django admin, but to no avail. My DRF configuration in `settings.py` is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

Edit: my own answer below

Comment: have you updated your django-cors-headers package?

Comment: Yes `django-cors-headers==3.11.0` which is the latest at the time of writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `urlpatterns` order in `urls.py` was the problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62485830/django-rest-framework-apiview-not-csfr-exempt) answer helped.

If the Django admin url is above the api urls, any api request will not even reach these apis and Django will throw the CSRF cookie error.

Working in Django 3.1, but not working in Django 3.2:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.MyLoginToken.as_view()),
    url(r'^', include('myapp.backend.urls')),
]
```

Working in Django 3.2:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('myapp.backend.urls')),  # move CSRF exempt apis to the top
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.MyLoginToken.as_view()),
    path('', admin.site.urls),  # move CSRF protected endpoints to the end
]
```

I couldn't find any documentation for this breaking change from Django 3.1 to Django 3.2.

Comment: Excellent answer. Problem was solved by moving `admin.site.urls` to the end. Still not sure why works. The link you shared points to a different problem I think.