# CSRF issue in django

Tags: django, backend, csrf, http-referer

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

ajax request

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: `https://example.com/requestlink/`,
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    link: link,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf,
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        data.forEach(src => {
                            createresult(src);
                        })
                    }
                    icon.classList.replace('loading', 'search');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    icon.classList.replace('loading', 'search');
                }
            })
```

Now when i do ajax post request,
I got this in console tab

```
Status 403 Forbidden
Version HTTP/1.1
Transferred 1.53 KB (2.50 KB size)
Referrer Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

and this in backend

Forbidden (Referer checking failed - https:// anotherexample.com / does not match any trusted origins.): /requestlink/

Why so?

Comment: `Referer` checking is not part of CORS. This isn't a CORS issue, but some other authorization issue. Check whatever the backend does to validate the `Referer` header.

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: => *Check whatever the backend does to validate the `Referer` header.*

Comment: how and in which file?

Comment: You must be using `django.middleware.csrf`, correct? From reading the source code, that middleware rejects the request if the host of the `Referer` header is different from the target origin's. You can deactivate that protection, if needed; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458166/how-to-disable-djangos-csrf-validation