# csrf cookie not set on linux

Tags: django, apache, django-rest-framework

I know this question is quite popular, before asking it, I researched all the previous questions and their answers, but never found a solution for myself.

My problem is that I am trying to remove the csrftoken validation completely in my application. I understand the vulnerabilities that open up in this case, but this is not critical for me. During development, no errors occur on my computer due to csrftoken, I develop on `windows`, but when I run it on `apache linux`, this error appears, **only when I am editing an already existing post** (no problem when creating a new post) it’s hard for me to imagine the reason why this happens only on a `apache linux` server, I transfer using docker .

I decided to remove csrftoken from my application for the same reason, on the `windows` computer on which I developed the application, no errors occurred with csrftoken enabled, but when transferred to a `apache linux` server, forms using data transfer using js files also gave an error `403`.

**Settings**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

**I removed in js files** csrf_token

```
{#                        {% csrf_token %}#}
```

**I removed in js files** `headers`

```
// headers: {'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value},
```

**I added in form attribute** `action=""`

```
<form class="js-edit-event-form" action="">
```

**I already cleared the cookie in my browser, used a different browser**, but the error still persists.

**I specifically made a mistake in the program** in order for django to generate a report, as a result I found the following information on the `apache linux` server (a distinctive feature is that this information is not available on the local machine on which I develop the project, on `windows`):

```
CSRF_COOKIE = 'ijijj34j24345678x6gfddsfvgnkjnhkhkhfd6'
CSRF_COOKIE_USED = True
```

**I tried passing the specified** `CSRF_COOKIE_USED` setting in the `settings.py` file:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_USED = False
```

but this did not lead to the desired result.

**I tried adding a decorator** but it didn't work:

```
class EventCard(CreateView):
    template_name = 'main/event_card.html'

    @csrf_exempt
    def get(self, request, Id_Events=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that when the session is enabled, the csrf token is implicitly added, even when it is disabled everywhere.

I used the following answer to solve the problem at hand:
[How to disable Django's CSRF validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458166/how-to-disable-djangos-csrf-validation/70732475#70732475)