# Django: Disable CSRF on debug not working

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I am debugging my Django project deployed in the cloud. It does not have a domain name yet. I cannot login though the `/admin/` page because of the CSRF error:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

I am also trying to debug it using my frontend deployed in machine at `localhost:3000`. The same case, I get a `403` response signifying the CSRF verification failure. I want to bypass this on `DEBUG=True` for the purpose of debugging my APIs.

I found this thread, and followed one of its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70732475/9879869. I created a Middleware supposedly disabling the CSRF when `DEBUG=True`.

```
#utils.py
from project import settings
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class DisableCSRFOnDebug(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        attr = '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks'
        if settings.DEBUG:
            setattr(request, attr, True)
```

I added it to my `MIDDLEWARE`. It is the last entry in the list.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "project.utils.DisableCSRFOnDebug"
]
```

After all of this, I still cannot login to my Django admin and my locally deployed frontend still gets the CSRF verification failure. I do not want the `csrf_exempt` option since it does not make sense placing it on an important endpoint/view -- the Login.

Here are my additional configuration on `settings.py`.

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'https://example.com',
]

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'https://example.com',
]
```

What is wrong with my configuration? How can I disable CSRF in Debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

first of all deactivating CSRF and security middlewares even in local development is not good idea it can cost you a lot during deployment better to find out why it's broken,and for your Middleware that doesn't work its because the Middleware ordering is matter!

[Read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/middleware/#middleware-ordering)

And i think the problem is in
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE =True
Due

> CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE¶ Default: False
>
> Whether to use a secure cookie for the CSRF cookie. If this is set to
> True, the cookie will be marked as “secure”, which means browsers may
> ensure that the cookie is only sent with an HTTPS connection.

Do you use https in local development?

This is good for read and more info too.
[Docs of Django CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/csrf/)