# CORS problem with django running on GCP compute engine code-server

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, cors, google-compute-engine

I am working on a Django project. For that, I work both in my personal laptop as well on a remote code-server instance (VS Code Remote) running on GCP compute engine.

I run code-remote on https://dev.myweb.com (fake url) and when running the django server via `python manage.py runserver` in port 8000 the built in proxy allows me to connect via https://dev.myweb.com/proxy/8000

I can get to the first page (base.html) without problem (no forms or request in that page). But when I click on login (which would bring a POST request, that I think is the problem?), I get a error like this:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help
Reason given for failure:

    Origin checking failed - https://dev.myweb.com does not match any trusted origins.
    
In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django’s CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function passes a request to the template’s render method.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.
You’re seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.

You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

I have the following enabled in the remote vscode instance

```
if os.environ.get("ENV") == "DEV-remote":
    USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
    FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "/proxy/8000"
    CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
    CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://dev.myweb.com",
    ]
    CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
        'DELETE',
        'GET',
        'OPTIONS',
        'PATCH',
        'POST',
        'PUT',
    ]
    CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "https://dev.myweb.com",
    ]
```

In case needed, the following django files:

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView as LoginViewOrig
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class LoginView(LoginViewOrig):
    template_name = "login.html"
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("home")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("login/", LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
```

login.html template

```
<!-- myapp/templates/myapp/login.html -->

{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block title %}Login - My Django App{% endblock %}
{% block header %}Login{% endblock %} {% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
            {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Research CSRF - Cross Site Request Forgery. Your application is expecting a hidden form field that is missing or has an invalid value.

Comment: Yep, I looked for it but cannot find the issue. I understand that it is preventing subdomains querying another subdomain, ie api.web.com making a post request to dev.web.com. But I cannot figure out how to solve it. In this case is the same subdomain (dev.web.com) which is making a post request to itself (dev.web.com)?? 
Also the POST request is sending a csrf token as usual.

Comment: What do your settings look like? -- Specifically for Middleware `If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.` is pretty explicit, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_protect. A fast solution would  be to add the correct decorator to your `LoginView(LoginViewOrig)` view: `@csrf_protect` but note with a class based view you need to use something more like `@method_decorator(csrf_protect, name='dispatch')`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by disabling CORS (only in DEV) with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43841990/15254876

Create a middleware inside your app (ie /yourapp/middleware.py) as:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class DisableCsrfCheck(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, req):
        attr = '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks'
        if not getattr(req, attr, False):
            setattr(req, attr, True)
```

And add to settings.py along with the rest of MIDDLEWARE

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
    "yourapp.middleware.DisableCsrfCheck"
...
]
```

Comment: I do not recommend disabling CSRF. That allows for security issues.