I can't get rid of CSRF checks
First of all, I know how necessary csrf is and what disasters will happen to me if I don't use it, I have read enough about it.
I want to disable csrf checks by taking all kinds of risks.
I have a backend using django rest framework and jwt authentication, I installed gunicorn and nginx on the server.
No matter what I do
<h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>

<p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>

<p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is

required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>

<p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for

“same-origin” requests.</p>

I can't get rid of this error.
Even removing all middleware didn't work.
Please help, I want to get rid of CSRF.
What should I do?

Have you already checked out https://stackoverflow.com/a/47888695/10951070?
