# Bypassing Django CSRF Protection using external POST Request

Tags: python, django, http-post, csrf, django-csrf

I have a Python program that needs to be able to send data to my website (built with Django).  This data will then be taken and displayed on a certain part of the website.  The problem I'm having is that the CSRF protection built into Django blocks my POST request.  From what I understand, this is usually avoided by adding {%csrf_token} to whatever form the POST request is being sent to.  My problem is that I'm trying to send the POST request to a .cgi script rather than a form.  Does anybody know how I could bypass the CSRF protection (preferably without removing it completely although this is an option.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django CSRF framework cannot be disabled and is breaking my site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650941/django-csrf-framework-cannot-be-disabled-and-is-breaking-my-site)

Answer (score 5):

You should use the csrf_exempt decorator to avoid csrf protection in certains view.

You can [read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/) for more information

Comment: It's no just the link, but also all the way Django manage this staff. New doc is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/. Note there were 4 releases between my original post and now.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using class based views, I'd recommend [django-braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/) which uses a [mixin](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form.html#csrfexemptmixin) to achieve this, as well as providing other extremely useful mixins.