# CsrfMiddleware disabled yet seeing 403 for Django AJAX request

Tags: ajax, django, csrf, django-csrf

I have excluded the line  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' from my django settings file in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and yet one of our users received the "Forbidden" Error from an AJAX request. How is this possible, especially if the CSRF Middleware is disabled?

Comment: There could be other middlewares that deal with CSRF themselves, which could be causing the issue. (_This is just a guess_ ) - Here is one way to overcome it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4631626/1628832

Comment: Thanks. I do see the csrftoken cached as a cookie, probably from the time that we had csrftokens enabled. Could a form being cached on the browser from a previous version of the website have anything to do with this?

Comment: @karthikr Also, the user apprised me of his windows password having expired in the meantime. Could this have anything to do with the forbidden on the ajax call? I understand I can disable all sources of csrf protection but I am also trying to figure what caused this as it's not replicable.

Comment: Well, I am not very convinced about the windows password expiry. However, I would guess that the user has logged out (session expiry/logout from another tab), which _could_ have caused the error.

Comment: I thought about that - but after checking the apache access logs I don't see any 403s. While if I enable Csrf and let it fail the 403s get logged into access.log. Which made me think that the request was somehow not reaching django...