# Clould9's Django out of the box: Admin page CSRF :443 error

Tags: django, django-admin, csrf, cloud9-ide, django-csrf

Clould9's Django out of the box gives CSRF error when I attempt to login to the admin page.
Reason given is:
 - Forbidden (403)
 - CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
 - Referer checking failed - https://mysite.c9.io/admin/login/?next=/admin/ does
   not match https://mysite.c9.io:443/

No changes were made to the instance, other than creating a superuser.

Commenting out setting.py MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' did not fix the issue.

Current workaround is through setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True), found here:
[Django CSRF framework cannot be disabled and is breaking my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650941/django-csrf-framework-cannot-be-disabled-and-is-breaking-my-site/3201582#3201582)

The problem seems to be the way Cloud9 treats HTTPS on port 443. **Is there a way to fix this without disabling CSRF for the whole site?** I also seem to be sandboxed out of django-admin.py, so I can't limit the hack to just the admin page.

Comment: i have the same problem...i am glad that you raised the issue @eff M and i guess it is an issue related to Django 1.7 since all is working correctly with other work spaces using Django < 1.7

Answer (score 2):

I have opened a ticket for this issue with the cloud9 support @eff M. They are great guys out there and great IDE as well with great support.

Meanwhile try this workaround for the time being:

access your admin page with http://mysite.c9.io/admin/login/?next=/admin/ and not with https://mysite.c9.io/admin/login/?next=/admin/ and see if you can login. it worked well on my side.

Comment: Logging in with HTTP allows easy interception of your credentials.  Don't use this in large-scale productions!