# Test post requests on django, csrf_token

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-csrf

I am trying test some of the post methods in my Django app, but due to the `csrf_token`, I can not test it without a browser. So I used 
    `@csrf_exempt` decorator
However I forget to remove those decorators in production. Is there a better way like this?

`@csrf_exempt(in_debug_only=True)`

So like this decorator is active only when the application is in debug mode. Or is there a better way to test post requests?

Like `selenium` might have some methods to do that?

Note: I m currently using Django 1.7.2 and Python 3.4.1

Comment: How exactly are you trying to test it? When I am running unit tests, Django doesn't enforce CSRF.

Comment: When you try to test a `post` view, due to the csrf security middle ware (really cool security feature ) , the request is rejected. Try

Comment: `response =request.post(url)`

Comment: I get default html , which on accepting should have been a json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4631626/4408382):

You can add a new file to your app, let's call it **disable_csrf.py**:

```
class DisableCSRF(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
```

Then you can edit your **settings.py** to add this:

```
if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += myapp.disable.DisableCSRF
```

Let me know if it worked.